# AsyncTask Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I am trying for two days without success, if anyone can help me here...

My get/set:

```
public class HTTPResult {

    private String id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;
    private String titulo;
    private String resumo;
    private String texto;
    private String fonte;
    private String link;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        email = email;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        nome = nome;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        this.id = ID;
    }

    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getResumo() {
        return resumo;
    }

    public void setResumo(String resumo) {
        this.resumo = resumo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public String getFonte() {
        return fonte;
    }

    public void setFonte(String fonte) {
        this.fonte = fonte;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Titulo: "+ getTitulo()
                     + "\nResumo: " + getResumo()
                     + "\nTexto: " + getTexto()
                     + "\nFonte: " + getFonte()
                     + "\nLink: " + getLink()
                     + "\nNome: " + getNome()
                     + "\nEmail: " + getEmail()
                     + "\nID: " + getID();

    }
}
```

The consumer JSON WebServ, that return a JsonArray from SQL

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PERSONS":
```

```
public class HTTPService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HTTPResult> {

    private final String command;

    public HTTPService(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }


    @Override
    protected HTTPResult doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/rest-FAKE/rest/fake" + command);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while (scanner.hasNext()){
                resposta.append(scanner.next());
                System.out.println(resposta);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), HTTPResult.class);
    }
}
```

The caller from Adaptador Class (ListView):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {

    String command = "/qnts";
    HTTPService service = new HTTPService(command);

    int valor = 0;
    try {
        HTTPResult retorno = service.execute().get();
        valor = Integer.parseInt(contagem);

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return valor;
}
```

and my dear problem:

```
2020-06-07 22:21:13.456 2825-2888/com.example.fakenewsbrasil I/System.out: [{"id":2}]
2020-06-07 22:21:13.482 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:123)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:193)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.get(AsyncTask.java:542)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.Adaptador.getCount(Adaptador.java:39)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:575)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.483 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err: Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
2020-06-07 22:21:13.484 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.HTTPService.doInBackground(HTTPService.java:45)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.HTTPService.doInBackground(HTTPService.java:13)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.485 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.486 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
2020-06-07 22:21:13.486 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.486 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
2020-06-07 22:21:13.486 2825-2825/com.example.fakenewsbrasil W/System.err:  ... 12 more
2020-06-07 22:21:13.489 2825-2888/com.example.fakenewsbrasil E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.fakenewsbrasil, PID: 2825
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813)
        at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.HTTPService.doInBackground(HTTPService.java:45)
        at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.HTTPService.doInBackground(HTTPService.java:13)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:215)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:927) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:892) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:841) 
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:813) 
        at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.HTTPService.doInBackground(HTTPService.java:45) 
        at com.example.fakenewsbrasil.HTTPService.doInBackground(HTTPService.java:13) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2020-06-07 22:21:13.507 2825-2888/com.example.fakenewsbrasil I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2825 SIG: 9
```

Help t-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response contain array it means you should parse it to List. Change `AsyncTask` to this

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HTTPResult>>
```

```
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<HTTPResult>>() {}.getType();
return new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), type);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i am getting somes bugs, but i am still trying solve. But i will come to give a feedback;

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a class for de-serialising by default it'll be an object. But in your scenario you are getting an array of objects, everything is fine just the return type of the AsyncTask should be updated.

You've used `AsyncTask<Void, Void, HTTPResult>`

```java
public class HTTPService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HTTPResult> {
```

This means that from the `AsyncTask` you will be returning an object of type `HTTPResult`, but where as from the backend you've got an array of objects so the type should be `List<HTTPResult>`.

Make below changes to your `HTTPService AsyncTask class`

```java
public class HTTPService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<HTTPResult>> {
...
//rest of your code
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<HTTPResult>() {}.getType();
return new Gson().fromJson(resposta.toString(), listType)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i am getting somes bugs, but i am still trying solve. But i will come to give a feedback;